# Convergence of multiple iterated series

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

I am searching for sources or references for this proposition. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Let $A_{n_1,n_2,...,n_k}$ be multiple sequence on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^k$ be bijection. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|A_{\phi(n)}|$ converge, then $\sum_{n_1=1}^\infty\sum_{n_2=1}^\infty\cdots\sum_{n_k=1}^\infty A_{n_1,n_2,...,n_k}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_{\phi(n)} $

In fact, I have already proven it using my own method. However, I would like to reference this proposition in my article. If there are existing documents that have presented the proof of this proposition, I would be able to reference them without wasting space in the article. Do you happen to have any references? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of change-of-variables formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#:%7E:text=In%20measure%20theory%2C%20a%20pushforward,another%20using%20a%20measurable%20function.). For completeness, let me add more hints:

1. View $A$ as a map from $\mathbb N^k$ to $\mathbb C$.
2. Denote $\mu$ as the counting measure on $\mathbb N$, and $\mu_k$ as the counting measure in $\mathbb N^k$.
3. View $\phi$ as a measurable map and $A\circ\phi \in L^1(\mu)$.
4. Verify the pushforward of $\mu$ through $\phi$ is $\mu_k$.
5. Check the conditions in the link and you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. In fact, I have already proven it using my own method. However, I would like to reference this proposition in the article. If there are existing documents that have presented the proof of this proposition, I would be able to reference them without wasting space in the article. Do you happen to have any references? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should appear as an easy exercise in some measure theory books if you want to look it up.